# In Microsoft Word 2016, what's the difference between the commands "ClearFormatting" and "ClearAllFormatting"?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Both of these have the same quick description in the Customize Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box: "Clears formatting and styles from selected text."

What's the difference?

I'm working on an iMac in MS Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have WORD on iMac... but IMHO

- ClearFormatting refers to text spacing and paragraph format
- ClearAllformatting does above and includes font styles.(such as bold, underline, italics, color, superscript, subscript, and more)